# Batch - Emoji Colors

Tags: batch-file, colors, emoji

I'm making a sport game in batch and I need:
So that one of the emoji people would be blue, and the other emoji people would be red.

How can I possibly do that? I thinks that you can maybe do it like this:

```
set (emoji)=color 04
```

I hope you understood me. Please help and ask questions if you don't get what I need.

---

Some of you were asking for my code:

```
@echo off
:start
title Sport Game
echo Pick A Team:
echo.
echo 1. Blue
echo 2. Red
set /p start=  
if %start%== 1 goto blue
if %start%== 2 goto red
echo Plase give me the number..
pause
goto start
:blue
cls
echo                                      You Are On Blue Team!
pause
:red
cls
echo                                      You Are On Red Team!
pause
```

Comment: Not really. Kinda is, but I'm looking to have multiple. I'm looking on how to make this emoji or letter to be made this color at the start then, have it be the same color in my batch without adding more codes to it.

Comment: Try `cecho.exe` BTW, show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `cecho.exe`. Simply put the `.exe` file into the Windows directory (%Windir%) and you can use it as a normal command.

---

### Usage

```
cecho.exe {04}text in red{#} text in original color{\n}

{xx} color code
{#}  revert to original color
{\n} newline
```

---

You can know more about this utility [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17033/Add-Colors-to-Batch-Files)(download link also inside)

Comment: @BobSmith - You've got batch code that you're going to share with the world and you're going to put it on _instructibles_?! Are you out of your damn mind? That is **not** a software distribution platform. Have some self-respect and stick it on GitHub or GameJolt or something that's _actually designed for that_.